# Can I have different desktop folders in each workspace?

Tags: workspaces, multiple-desktops

Is there any way that I can have different desktop folders in each workspace?

e.g. workspace1 has a desktop with a folder named test1, while the desktop folder in workspace2 has a different folder named randomfolder.

Right now if I change something in one workspace desktop all the workspaces will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Every workspace contains the same desktop, the same panels, and the same menus of your operating system. It's like cropping your office desk in pieces; each piece is the same as the other and you can run different procedures at each.

However everything you change at each workspace will remain untouched and not effect the other workspaces. For instance if I open *Terminal* at the 1st workspace it will remain as I left it when I changed workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible with the existing software. There is one way you can this effect though.

If you use Screenlets:
[image: Install via the software center]
there is a folder view screenlet that you can place on each workspace individually, showing a different folder in each one.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in Kubuntu. You can choose between all virtual desktops being the same and having different settings for each one. Then you can just use the desktop folder widget for each virtual desktop and have it display a different folder each time.